# Creating a list of lists based on other list

Tags: python

From the following list:

```
values = [('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4),('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7),('on',8)]
```

I'm attempting to create a list of lists containing:

```
[('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4)],
[('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7)('on',8)]
```

The logic is: find an `on`, continue until find another `on` and store all intermediary list elements in a sublist.

Here is my code:

```
%reset -f

values = [('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4),('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7),('on',8)]

    t_l = []
    for i,v in enumerate(values): 
        temp_list = []
        if v[0] == 'on' : 
            temp_list.append(v)
            for ii, v2 in enumerate(values, start=i+1):
                if v2[0] == 'on' : 
                    t_l.append(temp_list)
                    break
                else : 
                    temp_list.append(v2)
    
    t_l
```

`t_l` contains:

```
[[('on', 1)], [('on', 4)], [('on', 5)], [('on', 8)]]
```

The begin positions appear to be calculated correctly but intermediary values are not.

This line is not behaving as expected:

```
for ii, v2 in enumerate(values, start=i+1):
```

The start position is not being used, for example if I set `start=3000` an exception is not thrown, so it appears I've not configured `start` correctly.

Comment: The start value of enumerate simply states what *index* the first value of the array will get. It will not skip ahead in the iterator, there are other methods for that

Comment: Consider using [`itertools.islice(enumerate(values), start, None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple `if else` statements:

```
new_lst=[]
l=[]
x=0
for i in values:
    if i[0]=='on' and x==0:
        l.append(i)
        x=1
    elif i[0]!='on' and x==1:
        l.append(i)
    else:
        l.append(i)
        x=0
        new_lst.append(l)
        l=[]
print(new_lst)
```