# Update list of tuples such that invalid values are removed

Tags: python

From the following list:

```
values = [('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4),('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7),('on',8),
         ('off',9),('e1',10),('e2',11),('on',12)]
```

I'm attempting to create a list of lists containing:

```
[('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4)],
[('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7)('on',8)]
```

The logic is: find an on, continue until find another on and store all intermediary list elements in a sublist.

Based on the accepted answer to this question ([Creating a list of lists based on other list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917068/creating-a-list-of-lists-based-on-other-list)) I'm attempting to improve the solution such that if there is an 'off' followed by an 'on' then it's excluded from the list.

The below code works as expected for the above list :

```
values = [('on',1),('e1',2),('e2',3),('on',4),('on',5),('e1',6),('e2',7),('on',8),
         ('off',9),('e1',10),('e2',11),('on',12)]

new_lst=[]
l=[]
x=0

for i in values:
    if i[0]=='on' and x==0:
        l.append(i)
        x=1
    elif i[0]!='on' and x==1:
        l.append(i)
    else:
        l.append(i)
        x=0
        new_lst.append(l)
        l=[]

updated_list = []
for nl in new_lst : 
    len_on = len(list(filter(lambda x: 'on' in x[0] ,nl)))
    if len_on == 2 : 
        updated_list.append(nl)
        
for u in updated_list : 
    print(u)
```

prints :

```
[('on', 1), ('e1', 2), ('e2', 3), ('on', 4)]
[('on', 5), ('e1', 6), ('e2', 7), ('on', 8)]
```

Is there a solution that does not require another pass through the list to exclude values that are not valid ? To exclude the values I use :

```
updated_list = []
for nl in new_lst : 
    len_on = len(list(filter(lambda x: 'on' in x[0] ,nl)))
    if len_on == 2 : 
        updated_list.append(nl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `itertools.pairwise` function to loop over pairs of items directly -

```py
outer_list = []
inner_list = []
for pair in pairwise(values):
    (start1, val1), (start2, val2) = pair
    if start1 == 'on' and start2.startswith('e'):
        inner_list.append((start1, val1))
    if start1.startswith('e') and start2.startswith('e'):
        if inner_list:
            inner_list.append((start1, val1))
    if start1.startswith('e') and start2 == 'on':
        if inner_list:
            inner_list.append((start1, val1))
            inner_list.append((start2, val2))
            outer_list.append(inner_list[:])
        inner_list = []
    print(inner_list)
```

**Output**

```
[[('on', 1), ('e1', 2), ('e2', 3), ('on', 4)],
 [('on', 5), ('e1', 6), ('e2', 7), ('on', 8)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

At each element, you're looking to either start a chain or end one.
If you start a chain with "on", then you build up the sublist until the next "on" ends the chain. If you start one with "off", then you idle until the next "on" ends the chain.

`read_mode` = "currently building a chain"
`write_mode` = "started this chain with 'on'"

```
result = []
sublist = []
read_mode = False
write_mode = False

for i in values:
    if i[0] == "on":
        if read_mode:
            read_mode = False
            if write_mode:
                sublist.append(i)
                result.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
                write_mode = False
        else:
            read_mode = True
            write_mode = True
            sublist.append(i)
    elif i[0] == "off":
        read_mode = True
    else:
        if read_mode and write_mode:
            sublist.append(i)
```

Same output for your example input.